# Restart socketio on system boot using pm2 (Not Cluster mode)

Tags: socket.io, state, pm2

I am developing an express.js app an I am NOT running it in cluster mode using pm2 -i option, since I only have a CPU.
I have used previously in some apps, pm2 to start express.js server on boot and to restart it if its process is killed.

I would like to know 2 things:

**1**. I want to run a express.js server in conjunction with a socket.io server, both listening on the same port (4000) as it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#in-conjunction-with-express). Will also socket.io server be started on system boot and when its process is killed?

$ pm2 start app.js

```
//app.js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen(4000);
```

**2**.Will I have any problem with app state in the backend such as sessions since [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) says "Be sure your application is stateless meaning that no local data is stored in the process, for example sessions/websocket connections, session-memory and related" and [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1510) says long-polling (used by socket.io as a fallback) needs some state. I guess that that problems only arises when using pm2 in cluster mode but I want to make sure by anyone that has experienced it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because you are attaching your socket.io instance to your server object, they will both be accessible on the same port and will both start when the server does. My socket connection is set up the same way and I am also using PM2. To start the server when the machine boots, you need to tell PM2 to do that. Check this link: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

global.io = require('socket.io')(server, { transports: [ 'websocket' ]})
```

2. You will have an issue with sessions if you are storing them in local memory. I use connect-mongo and passport-socketio for sessions since I am using MongoDB and passport in my architecture. This saves all the sessions in my database and creates a "sessions" collection in which they are stored and prevents them from being destroyed when I deploy or restart the server for whatever reason. If you are storing session data in memory only, it will be wiped on server restart.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })

const expressSession = session({
    resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, secret: process.env.passportSecret, cookie: { maxAge: 36000000 }, store: sessionStore, key: 'connect.sid'
})

app.use(expressSession)

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  key: 'connect.sid',
  secret: process.env.passportSecret,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookieParser: cookieParser
}))
   .on('connection', async (socket) => {
})
```

Using this setup with PM2, I've yet to see any issues whatsoever with socket.io in regular mode. For cluster mode, you simply need to set up Redis server. For Ubuntu follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04

```
npm i socket.io-redis
```

```
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis')

global.io = require('socket.io')(server, { transports: [ 'websocket' ]})

io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }))
```

Here is the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis

It was as simple as that to get my sockets working in cluster mode.